JXLS not writing the variables in excel output file
I am new to JXLS and am trying to do their Hello World like in this tutorial but i get blank output instead of processed variables.
The Steps to get my situation:

Open a new java project with Maven

Add these required dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>


Create an Excel file called object_collection_template.xlsx"

Add this text as an Excel comment to the cell A1:Author: jx:area(lastCell="D4")

Add this text as an Excel comment to the cell A4: Author: jx:each(items="employees" var="employee" lastCell="D4")

The final content of the file is : 

Have this java code:
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Test> users = new ArrayList<>(); //userRepository.findAll();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        users.add(new Test((i + 1), "login-" + (i + 1), "password " + "-" + (i + 1)));
    }

    try {
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("employees", users);
        JxlsPoiTemplateFillerBuilder.newInstance()
                .withTemplate("object_collection_template.xlsx")
                .build()
                .fill(data,   new JxlsOutputFile(new File("result_object_collection_template.xlsx")) );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    System.out.println();

}

static class Test {
int id;
String login;
    String password;

    public Test(int id, String login, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

   public int getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getLogin() {
       return login;
   }

   public void setLogin(String login) {
       this.login = login;
   }

   public String getPassword() {
       return password;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
       this.password = password;
   }

}
}


The output that i get:

As you can see, the iteration is exactly as the size of the list (5 elements) but there is no output in the first column neither in the second column as those two columns use the syntax provided in the official documentation : ${variable.thatShouldBePrinted}.
The question is:
What am i missing to get the correct output in these two columns (id & login) ?
What i tried

Reading documentation carefully to find if i am missing something, specially in the template configuration.
Playing with different possible syntaxes in the template
Searching for this issue (or a similar one) on the internet
Playing with different versions of the library

But no point of the above did help me, so i will be very thankful for anyone who can help me getting rid of this problem.

In case anyone gets in this situation: I found the solution. The problem was because of the inner static class Test. When i moved it outside in a separate file, everything works now.
